# Can Amazon Chime Screen Sharing feature is possible with react native application?

Tags: screensharing, amazon-chime

I am trying to add the screen sharing feature in react native app using the Amazon Chime SDK but i can't find any code or any reference from any platform so I am asking this question is it possible or not?